# How to consume a type which implements both IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable?

Tags: c#, async-await, using, idisposable, iasyncdisposable

I'm currently working with ASP.NET core 3.1 and C# 8.

This is the very first time that I'm touching on the whole `IAsyncDisposable` story, so it is entirely possible that my understanding is only partial and that this question is a dumb one.

Based on my understanding a type should implement the `IAsyncDisposable` interface when it needs to release the resources that it owns in an asyncronous way, so that the required disposal can be carried on without blocking a thread. Put another way, `IAsyncDisposable` is the asyncronous counterpart of `IDisposable` which allows to release class resources in an efficient manner (in terms of threads usage).

The language supports the consumption of types implementing the `IAsyncDisposable` by means of the new `await using` construct, which is basically the asyncronous counterpart of the `using` keyword.

So far so good.

I have noticed that there are some BCL types which implements both `IAsyncDisposable` and `IDisposable`, one of them being the `Stream` abstract class. I have encountered this scenario while working on uploaded files in ASP.NET core and calling the [`IFormFile.OpenReadStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method.

My question now is the following: how should I consume a type implementing both `IAsyncDisposable` and `IDisposable` ? Should I use the classic `using` keyword or should I opt for `await using` ?

The piece of code I was writing is a syncronous one, so the most natural way to deal with the stream is the following:

```
using var readStream = uploadedFile.OpenReadStream();

var options = new LoadOptions(loadFormat);
return new Workbook(readStream, options);
```

Should I make my method `async` in order to being able to use `await using` in the following manner ?

```
await using var readStream = uploadedFile.OpenReadStream();

var options = new LoadOptions(loadFormat);
return new Workbook(readStream, options);
```

(consider that, apart the `await using` call, my method does **not** need to be asyncronous)

What is the difference in calling `Dispose` versus `DisposeAsync` for a type implementing both of them ?

Comment: There is no difference in that the types are complementary. Obviously `IDisposable` existed before `IAsyncDisposable` did and synchronous disposing isn't going to become unsupported suddenly. If your code is synchronous you shouldn't mess with asynchronous disposal (and ideally, vice versa). Only if you plan on making the rest of the code asynchronous (i.e. consuming the stream using `async` methods) does asynchronously disposing the resource start to make sense. (Incidentally, ASP.NET can make good use of asynchrony, so that *is* worth considering.)

Comment: Based on the documentation of the [`Stream.Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.dispose) and [`Stream.DisposeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.disposeasync) methods, I think that calling any of them should be enough for releasing the unmanaged resources used by the `Stream`. You don't have to call both, although calling them both should not cause any harm (provided that you don't call them concurrently of course).